# Setup NSG inbound security rules for multiple VM

Tags: azure, network-security-groups, inbound-security-rule

In my NSG I have inbound security rules like this:

```
Priority Name Port Protocol Destination
-------- ---- ---- -------- -----------
340      RDP  3389 TCP      10.0.0.4
350      Tn   22   TCP      10.0.0.5
```

In NSG -> Network Interfaces

```
Name  Public IP   Private IP 
----- ----------  -----------
Svr1  137.116.x.x 10.0.0.4
Svr2  -           10.0.0.5
```

The NSG is only able to port forward port 3389 to Svr1 (10.0.0.4), where the public IP address was associated with.

I can't port forward any other port to Svr2 (10.0.0.5) or another VM within the subnet, where it Public IP address is not associated with.

My I know what is wrong with my setting?

Comment: Is the NSG attached directly to NIC or subnet?

Comment: Kasun, may I know how to check that?

Comment: Go to NIC of the VM then under Network security group you can find the NSG attached. If its attached to subnet go to VNET then select the subnet, under the subenets it shows any NSG attached

Comment: Kasun, my NSG is associated to both NIC and Subnet. I have removed from the NIC. Now may I know how to associate the Public IP to my NSG? Thanks

Comment: you cant associate IP to NSG

Answer (score 0):

you need to assign public ip to any vm you want to access externally. alternatively you need to assign all the vms to the same load balancer and configure NATing\load balancing